# How to Set a Outlook rule to classify email received by BCC?

Tags: outlook, rules, bcc

I am in diff distribution list like  A , B , C

There are a lot of email BCC to A , B ,C

I want to setup rules that "Move all mail bcc to specific Distribution list  to specific folder "

It seems that no rules on "BCC" ,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This rule should help:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives 
where my name in not in the To Box
move it to [folderOfYourChoice] folder 
except where my name is in the Cc box
```

[image]

Comment: In Outlook 2016, you can just use "except if my name is in the To or Cc box"

Comment: Unfortunately, this rule would incorrectly move messages sent to mailing lists also.

Comment: @StephenGrimes just move this rule down to the end in the list of all other rules..

Answer (score 41):

You can create a rule based on BCC you receive, but it's not immediately obvious as you have to resort to the message headers. The steps are:

1. Send yourself a BCC mail.
2. When it arrives, open it up and display the "Properties" or "Message Options" dialog. You get to "Properties" under the File tab of the ribbon. One way to get to message options is to click on the small icon to the right of the "Tags" label on the Message tab of the ribbon.
3. Scroll down the Internet headers until you find something that identifies it as BCC. In my case it was `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc`
4. Create a rule and choose "with specific words in the message header".
5. Copy in the value you found for step 3.
6. Save your rule, send yourself another BCC, and enjoy.

Comment: I found that mine also used the same, but my rule is not sending... strange

Comment: On Mac, click on "View Source" of the email to get header information mentioned in step 3. of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this rule is that some email senders use `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc` and some (GMail in this example) use `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous`.

I created this rule:

```
my name NOT in the to line
```

This catches CC and BCC but that is OK for my purposes.

Comment: The GMail example was helpful but this wouldn't work for distribution lists.

Answer (score -1):

I did this in Outlook 2011 by setting up a rule that sends everything to my bcc folder unless I am addressee or cc'd. That seems to work.

Answer (score -4):

If an email sent to you was BCC'd, you would never know it. That is the point of BCC -- only the sender knows who was BCC'd. I'm afraid there's no way to tell, although I would love to hear otherwise.

Comment: If you're BCCed there's a header field that has (only) your address in it.

Comment: @Dan What field is that?

Comment: The header field is BCC:

Comment: @Dan Please provide an example of how to view this header. I sent an email to myself (Outlook 2003) and go to View > Options and look at the Internet Headers. There is no "BCC". I run the following code snippet and get 0: `?Len(ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.BCC)`

Comment: Here's an example from one I got (I am part of quotes@andovar.com) today:

Subject: A freelance English< >Chinese translator
From: Jack Zhang <Jack303Zhang@hotmail.com>
To: undisclosed-recipients:;
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="f46d042ef593fd2a5004c580f3da"
BCC: <quotes@andovar.com>
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply

Comment: @Dan This is very short on details. Please explain how to view the BCC header. What Outlook version?

Comment: Outlook 2010.  Open the mail in it's own window, click the file tab, click properties and you'll get all the headers for that mail.  IIRC in 2003 you need to open the mail and find the 'Options' option.

Comment: The client, at least in 2007, can not tell.  It can only guess based on whether or not the account is in the CC and To fields, but even that won't be accurate all the time.  "NOTE   Recipients of blind carbon copies (Bcc) do not appear in the header." - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-e-mail-message-headers-HA001230300.aspx